# Vagrant's Ubuntu 16.04 vagrantfile default password

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm attempting to deploy and run an Ubuntu 16.04 VM via Vagrant 1.9.1.
The Vagrantfile I'm using is from Atlas:

[Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 Vagrantfile](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/xenial64/)

I'm using Debian Stretch as the host OS. Vagrant was installed via a .deb available from Vagrant's website.

The Vagrantfile does run and deploy correctly. I can ssh into the VM via both my host OS and using 'vagrant ssh'. However, I have one minor blocker when attempting to ssh in from outside.

The default user in this VM is named 'ubuntu', and looks to have a password set. However, I have no idea what the password is at all, and no docs seem to have the information that I'm looking for. Attempting to set a password via 'passwd' within the VM asks for a current password. Anyone see where this is going?

So my big question is this: has anyone else deployed this same Vagrantfile, and if so, does anyone know what the default user's password is?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this breaks the vagrant standard of having the user/pass both default to 'vagrant'.  

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/base.html

Answer (score 32, accepted):

<sup>As of writing this answer: no one ever publicly shared the password for user `ubuntu` on `ubuntu/xenial64` Vagrant box (see [#1569237](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1569237)).</sup>

It's not necessary. You can:

- login using SSH key authentication
- change the password using `sudo passwd ubuntu` (by default `ubuntu` user has sudo-permissions with `NOPASSWD` set)

Actually, not only you can, but you **should** change the password.

Comment: Thanks for linking to the Launchpad bug report!

Following through the comments, I found a link to another Ubuntu 16.04 Vagrantfile which I downloaded and tested:

https://atlas.hashicorp.com/bento/boxes/ubuntu-16.04

This one used the old username and password of "vagrant/vagrant", which allowed me to do my tests headache-free. :)

Comment: How to add my public SSH key to the virsual machine if I can't login to it because I don't know login and password?

Comment: @Finesse not sure if you still need an answer to this, but you can usually login without password by typing the command `vagrant ssh`

Comment: you could also delete the user `sudo deluser --remove-home ubuntu` and then created your own

Answer (score 29):

The password is located in the `~/.vagrant.d/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-xenial64/20161221.0.0/virtualbox/Vagrantfile` as mention by user @prometee in this launchpad discussion [#1569237](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1569237).

Here is mine (line 8):

```
# Front load the includes
include_vagrantfile = File.expand_path("../include/_Vagrantfile", __FILE__)
load include_vagrantfile if File.exist?(include_vagrantfile)

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.base_mac = "022999D56C03"
  config.ssh.username = "ubuntu"
  config.ssh.password = "fbcd1ed4fe8c83b157dc6e0f"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--uart1", "0x3F8", "4" ]
     vb.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--uartmode1", "file", File.join(Dir.pwd, "ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg-console.log") ]
  end
end
```

FYI, user @racb mention in the same discusison that the `this bug report having been filed` [to ubuntu](https://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2016/07/06/%23ubuntu-devel.html#t12:30) and so far `no [...] decision has been made yet` about it.

Comment: The path of the mentioned `Vagrantfile` has changed some (probably as a result of a more recent `vagrant` version). It now has `/boxes` in the path, like so: `~/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-xenial64/20171028.0.0/virtualbox/Vagrantfile`.

Answer (score 26):

The default user and password is:

user: `vagrant`
password: `vagrant`

Answer (score 3):

The new `ubuntu/xenial64` image doesn't come with a default username and password. However you can ssh using an ssh-key generated in your vagrant folder.

Let's say your Vagrantfile is at `/vagrant/vm01/Vagrantfile`, the ssh-key would be in `/vagrant/vm01/.vagrant/machines/..../private_key`

You can login to your vagrant vm using this `private_key`. If the guest machine ask for the key's passphrase, just hit `ENTER` (specifying a blank passphrase). For example, on my Mac:

```
ssh -i /vagrant/vm01/.vagrant/..../private_key <your vm user>@<your vm ip>:<your vm port>
```

If you still want to log in using username and password, after logging in using the private_key, you can add your own user for logging in later:

```
# create a user for log in
sudo useradd yourusername

# specify a password
sudo passwd yourusername
# then type your password when prompted

# add the user to sudo group
sudo adduser yourusername sudo    

# create a home folder for your user
sudo mkdir /home/yourusername

# add a shell command for your user (normally /bin/bash)
sudo vim /etc/passwd
# find yourusername line, and add /bin/bash to the end.
# the end result would look like this:
yourusername:x:1020:1021::/home/yourusername:/bin/bash
```

Now you can ssh using the new username and password.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the ubuntu 16.X password when you install through vagrant, but you can change that by your own by following below steps -

```
[~/from-vagrant-project]vagrant ssh
[ubuntu@hostname]sudo -i
root@hostname:~# passwd ubuntu
Enter new UNIX password:XXXXX
Retype new UNIX password:XXXXX
passwd: password updated successfully`
```

Answer (score -1):

if this can help:

I solved the custom packaging issue by creating a normal VM (in my case ubuntu/xenial), then copying the Identify file found with `vagrant ssh-config` and using that file for `config.sshprivate_key_path`, plus also setting `config.ssh.username` to `ubuntu`.
(see also https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/5186#issuecomment-355012068)